# Java: Help with an int[] method...has to do with Huffman Trees

Tags: java, arrays, integer, huffman-code

I am making a method to create the codewords for a huffman tree.  The symbol of the node to get the codeword from is passed into the method. I'm not exactly positive how to go about this it has to return an int[]. I coded up what I thought might work.  How do I properly use int[] so that I can create an output such as 00101? Thanks

```
public int[] codeWordAsAry(int k) { 
    HuffTreeNode temp;
    int[] codeWord;
    int pos = 0;
    temp = leaves[k];
    while (temp.parentOf() != null){
        if (temp.isLeftChild()){
            codeWord[pos] = 1;
            pos++;
        }
        else { //if isRightChild
            codeWord[pos] = 0;
            pos++;
        }
    }

    return codeWord; }
```

Ok so I understand the initializing the size but now I'm just wondering if its possible using this way to print out something along the lines of 01011 or other combinations like is the way im doing the increment of positions correct in the int[] array. will that print out what im looking for?

Comment: You will need to allocate space in your result array, something along the lines of `int[] codeWord = new int[10];`  I don't know how you can determine what the correct length is, though.

Comment: Can you change the return type to ArrayList<Integer>? Or you have to do it for int[] only? Because what I can see from the code is, for each letter the huffman code length would be different...so you won't be able to get the int[] size until u traverse till root...

Comment: "has to" return int[] because... ? Homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the integer array before attempting to access it.

For example,

```
int[] codeWord = new int[size];
```

Comment: @Babban It means what it sounds like: the size of the array. This is not magic; matt b means to determine the size that is needed, and then use it as shown.